# what is quickblox's android videochat service?

Tags: quickblox

please help - 
the documentation is not up to date, and i cant find the right answer

the doc says add this to the manifest

```
<service android:name="com.quickblox.module.chat.videochat.VideoChatService"/>
```

the example code on github says

```
<service android:name="com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.service.QBVideoChatService"/>
```

but there is no such thing as a 'service' inside the core namespace

please see attached image 
[image]

i use the currently last sdk - 1.2.4

thanks allot!
dovi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, don't use this service stuff at all now

Here is updated VideoChat guide http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android
which works with latest Android SDK 1.2.4

Comment: i have managed to get it working. thanks! for anyone else: something that is missing from this guide is using the onCameraDataReceive function. see sample on github..